# Write file from beginning

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm writing my first server script for find and remove malware js-code, but I can't find a simple method to rewrite an existing file from the beginning, as opposed to at the end.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import re
import codecs

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in filenames:
        f = open(os.path.join(dirname, filename), 'r+b')
        text=f.read()
        if re.search('function g\(\).*\n.*\<script src=\"http://linkfooter.org/linkfooter.js\"></script>\'\);}', text) and os.path.join(filename) != "bezr.py":
            print "starting with " + os.path.join(filename)
            match = re.compile('function g\(\).*\n.*\<script src=\"http://linkfooter.org/linkfooter.js\"></script>\'\);}')
            s = match.sub('', text)
            f.write(s)
        f.close()
        #else:
            #print "in " + os.path.join(dirname, filename) + " none"    
            #f.close()
```

Answer (score 5):

`f.seek(0)` before you write. `f.truncate()` afterward to cut off any extra text.

Comment: Yeah, i know. But, maybe using wrong, if file contain more text (in my case - necessarily) - it join to replaced text. For exmaple: file contain "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",  f.seek(0) f.write("aa") it will in file: "aaAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", not just "aa".

Answer (score 1):

```
filepath = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
text = file.read(filepath)
if re.search('function g\(\).*\n.*\<script src=\"http://linkfooter.org/linkfooter.js\"></script>\'\);}', line) and os.path.join(filename) != "bezr.py":
    with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
            print "starting with " + os.path.join(filename)
            match = re.compile('function g\(\).*\n.*\<script src=\"http://linkfooter.org/linkfooter.js\"></script>\'\);}')
            s = match.sub('', text)
            f.write(s)
```

Comment: this is wrong, you removed text=f.read() , and with "w" you can't read(). kindall's answers is correct

Comment: I'm suggesting a different approach: Either read through the file and iterate through its lines, or read the entire contents and just search the entire string in once (Actually, this is probably the best approach). Then, write to the newly opened file ('w' overwrites its content).

Comment: sorry, you're right, I didn't see readlines code. Still you're opening file twice without any need

Comment: Updated my answer now. Yes, I know I'm opening it twice so the other solution may be better if I/O is an issue.